# error executing arguments Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args) on absolute path

Tags: java, batch-file, runtime, runtime.exec

I'm trying to execute the following command:

*

> "cmd /c C:\stuff\dev\phantomjs\bin\phantomjs.exe downloadDocument.js
>   https://www.google.com"

*

When I put it on some batch Windows file, it will work. The problem is, I'm trying to do that with java, had no luck so far, tried also different paths (may be a dot issue).
Had no luck so far.
I really need a help here!
I am getting an error in the output stream of the process saying

> "Can't open 'downloadDocument.js'"

The only guess I have, is that I need to be in some *current path* to be able to execute the code.

What am I missing..?

here is the code:

```
public class UrlUtils {
    private static String SCRIPT_PATH = "C:\\stuff\\dev\\phantomjs\\bin\\phantomjs.exe";
    private static String SCRIPT_NAME = "downloadDocument.js";

    public static String execPhantom(String url) throws Exception {
        Process p;
        try{

            File f = new File(SCRIPT_PATH);

            String [] args = new String[5];
            args[0] = "cmd";
            args[1] = "/c";
            args[2] = f.getCanonicalPath().toString();
            args[3] = SCRIPT_NAME;
            args[4] = url;

            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
           .......
           .......
```

Comment: You could try also giving the complete path to downloadDocument.js, maybe that helps

Comment: You can also try using the .exec version that takes two addional parameters   (environment and working directory). Take a look at the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])

Comment: Dennis van Gils, U are acctually right, my EXE file and my JS script are at the same location, but, I am running my java code in a different location (depends on my workspace) so basically, so if I run the EXE file it doesn't threat the "current location" as the EXE location, it threat it as the parent location, (or the location of the Thread that run the EXE, which is my java workspace code). hope it make sense. and Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Also, if you use @DennisvanGils instead of my name I can see a notification when you message me.